# Connecting to a Reliable Webservice with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, httprequest

My application needs to receive a result from Reliable Webservice. Here is the scenario:-

First I send a `CreateSequence` request. Then the server replies with a `CreateSequenceResponse`  message. Next I send the actual request to the webservice.

Then the webservice send a response with `202 accept code` and sends result in a later message.  All these messages contain the header `Connection: keep-alive`.

I made request with `http.ClientRequest`. I could capture all responses except the result. `http.ClientRequest` fires only one `response` event.

**How can I receive the message which contains the result?**

Is there any way to listen to socket  for remaining data `(socket.on('data')` did not work). I checked this with `ReliableStockQuoteService` shipped with `Apache Synapse`. I appreciate if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the `response` event, you are given a single argument, which is an `http.IncomingMessage`, which is a `Readable` stream. This means that you should bind your application logic on the `data` event of the response object, not on the request itself.

```
req.on('response', function (res) {
  res.on('data', console.log);
});
```

*Edit:* [Here is a good article](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request) on how to make HTTP requests using Node.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is the case.'response' event occurs only once. The problem is server sends two separate messages for the last request. How can I capture the second message.